# Error While Printing on I2C OLED Display in Arduino

Tags: arduino

```
    #define OLED_RESET -1
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(OLED_RESET);
char buff[10]="hola";
char buff2[10]="";
int cnt=0;
int b=0;
int alpha=1;
void setup()
{
  
  display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);
  display.clearDisplay();
  
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
while (Serial.available()) {
  
  char a = Serial.read();
  buff[cnt++] = a;
  
  alpha=1;
}
  if(alpha==1){
      display.clearDisplay();  
    display.setCursor(0,0);
    display.setTextSize(1);
   display.println(buff);
   display.display(); 
   cnt=0;
 alpha=0;
  }
}
```

it prints first incoming string at place where i wat but when it receives second string it shifts to new line mean changes y position and after that it does not print any thing on display. Could any one can tell me the error i have made here.

Comment: `display.println(buff);` is printing a non-terminated char buffer. You need to terminate it with `buff[cnt++] = '\0';` first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you are building from the received characters isn't null-terminated when you print it.  Add

```
buff[cnt++] = '\0';
```

before calling `println`.

Comment: `while (Serial.available()) {
  
  char a = Serial.read();
  buff[cnt++] = a;
  alpha=1;
}
  if(alpha==1){
      display.clearDisplay();  
    display.setCursor(0,0);
    buff[cnt+1] = '\0';
   display.print(buff);
   display.display(); 
 alpha=0;
  }` problem is still same it only accept 2 string and then it does not print any string to the oled

Comment: @RjChoudhary I just saw you have low serial speed, so I'm guessing the lcd is printing one char only, then clearing the display to print the next. If you add a small delay at the end of your loop() does that help? `delay(200);`

Answer (score 1):

this code does the same thing as yours but with strings(I thing it is more useful than char arrays) Don't forget to replace "MaxLength" in line 15 with your own number

```
#define OLED_RESET -1
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(OLED_RESET);
String input;
void setup() {
  display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() > 0){ //if input available
    input = Serial.readString(); //Serial input to string
      if(input.length() > MaxLength) input = ""; // check if string isn't too long, replace 20 with your value
    display.clearDisplay();  
    display.setCursor(0,0);
    display.setTextSize(1);
    display.print(input); //I removed "ln" from println to not send \n at end of string
    display.display(); 
  }
}
```

I hope this will work

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, i hope this will work fine.